# text color for hint in EditText not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I got this `EditText` in my Layout file:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextFtpIp"
        android:hint="www.example.com"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#D3D3D3"
        android:ems="10" />
```

I set the `textColorHint` to light gray.
Unfortunality that has absolutly no effect in my emulator.
The hint color is always white.

what did I wrong?

my minSdkVersion is 12. targetSdk 21.

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely should work, try again with this

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="text"
        android:textColorHint="#ff2851" />
```